# Given PDF: Calculate $P(\cup_{i=1}^{n}{X_i>3/4})>0.99$. Result doesn't match given solution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

> Let $n\geq1$ and $X_1,....,X_n$ be independent random variables.
>
> Assume for $i = 1,...,n$  that  $X_i$ is absolute continuous with a density function $f_{Xi}$ given by;
>
> \begin{array}{ll}
>       3x^2 & 0<x< 1 \\
>       0 & otherwise \\
> \end{array}
>
> 1) Calculate $P(X_i\leq3/4)$ for $i = 1,...,n$
>
> 2) Calculate $P(\cup_{i=1}^{n}{X_i>3/4})>0.99$

Since others might seek help to a similar problem later I've written the entire task.

1) We solve the integral;

$\int_0^{3/4}(3·x^2)dx=\frac{27}{64}$

This matches the given solution.

2) In this task my idea is to solve the integral:

$\int_{3/4}^1(3·x^2)dx=\frac{37}{64}$

Having calculated this I use the formula: (since independence is present)

$P(A_1\cup A_2\cup ...\cup A_n=1-(1-P(A_1))(1-P(A_2))...(1-P(A_n))$

Using this formula we get:

$1-(1-\frac{37}{64})^n >.99$

I solve for this and get:

$5.33<n$

However this doesn't match the given result which is $n=6$

Am I doing something wrong or is it simply that I should interpret "$i = 1,...,n$" as "i" having to be a natural number and therefore I need to round to the nearest natural number?

Comment: > Am I doing something wrong or is it simply that I should interpret "$i=1,\ldots,n$" as "i" having to be a natural number and therefore I need to round to the nearest natural number?
$$\;$$
exactly!
Additional a hint: You don't need to solve the second integral. Just use complementing probability rule, because obviously: $$P\left(X_i > \frac{3}{4}\right) = 1 - P\left(X_i \le \frac{3}{4}\right)  = \frac{37}{64}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really glad with the fast response. Fine idea with the complementing probability rule as well, makes the task even faster to solve.

Comment: Yeah… Actually you don't need to find the complementing probability at all… you already had $$P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i\right) = 1 - \prod_{i=1}^n P(A_i^c)$$ but $$A_i^c = \left\{X_i \le \frac{3}{4}\right\}$$ hence $$P\left(A_i^c\right) = \frac{27}{64}$$ and so $$P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i\right) = 1 - \left(\frac{27}{64}\right)^n$$

Comment: I'll save that method. Thank you.

Comment: $1 - (27/64)^6 = 0.9948631$ and $1 - (27/64)^5 = 0.9876334,$ so 6 is the smallest integer that gives at least  .99. // @Gono. The 'usual' rule, often broken, is not to use Comments for Answers. (Perhaps the only harm here is that you can't get reputation points for my up-vote of your nice answer because it's in the form of a Comment.)

Comment: @BruceET, thank you for the response. Very quick way to solve it! Regarding the answer in comments part. How do I mark the question as answered? Is it alright for me to post an answer saying "Answer can be found in comments"? I've pondered about what is appropriate.

Comment: Added my comment(s) as an answer… @BruceET Actually I totally agree with you… but for some members it's a no go to post an "answer" that don't need much effort and get reputation points for it. So I started to post easy and short answers as a comment :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I doing something wrong or is it simply that I should interpret "$i=1,\ldots,n$" as "$i$" having to be a natural number and therefore I need to round to the nearest natural number?

exactly!

Additional a hint: You don't need to solve the second integral. Just use complementing probability rule, because obviously:
$$P\left(X_i > \frac{3}{4}\right) = 1 - P\left(X_i \le \frac{3}{4}\right)  = \frac{37}{64}$$

Actually you don't need to find the complementing probability at all… you already had $$P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i\right) = 1 - \prod_{i=1}^n P(A_i^c)$$
but $$A_i^c = \left\{X_i \le \frac{3}{4}\right\}$$ hence $$P\left(A_i^c\right) = \frac{27}{64}$$
and so $$P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i\right) = 1 - \left(\frac{27}{64}\right)^n$$

Comment: People are entitled to different opinions. Mine is that your formal Answer is fine. The Question shows some effort, but leads to a wrong answer. You saw the error and gave an Answer showing a rigorous approach that avoids the error. (And now your answer has been accepted, so the Question is off the list of those needing answers.)